# what is the difference between USB host and USB Accessory?

Tags: android, usb, accessory

Can anyone please tell me what is the difference between USB Host and USB Accessory?

To send digital Data from android device through USB what mode should I use?

Thanks..

Answer (score 5):

Here you go:

> - When the Android-powered device is in host mode, it acts as the USB host and powers the bus.
> - When the Android-powered device is in USB accessory mode, the connected USB hardware (an Android USB accessory in this case) acts as the host and powers the bus.

Taken from [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html) documentation from the Android developer site.

Comment: Thnks..I have already went through this link..But didn't get any clear Idea..

Comment: please tell me in simple words what is exact difference between these things?